# Why are references to wp_postmeta so slow?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, performance, indexing, entity-attribute-value

Fetching of attributes in WordPress (using MySQL) seems to be slower than necessary.

(This is a self-answered question, so proceed to my answer.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The standard schema for `wp_postmeta` provides poor indexes.  This leads to performance problems.

By changing the schema to this, most references to meta data will be faster:

```
CREATE TABLE wp_postmeta (
    post_id …,
    meta_key …,
    meta_value …,
    PRIMARY KEY(post_id, meta_key),
    INDEX(meta_key)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Notes:

- The current `AUTO_INCREMENT` column is a waste of space, and slows down queries because it is the `PRIMARY KEY`, thereby eschewing the "natural" "composite" PK of `(post_id, meta_key)`.
- InnoDB further boosts the performance of that PK due to "clustering".  (I hope you are not still using MyISAM!)
- If you are using MySQL 5.6 (Or MariaDB 10.0 or 10.1), change `meta_key` from `VARCHAR(255)`, not `VARCHAR(191)`.  (We can discuss the reasons, and workarounds, in a separate question, if 191 is not sufficient.)
- `INDEX(meta_key)` is optional, but needed if you want to "find posts that have a particular key".
- Caveat:  These changes will speed up *many* uses of postmeta, but not all.  I don't *think* it will slow down any use cases.  (Please provide such queries if you encounter them.  It could be a caching issue, not ar real degradation.)

If you would like to present *your* `CREATE TABLE`, I can provide an `ALTER` to convert it to this.

If you need the ability to have multiple meta keys with the same key name for one post, then use this solution. It is nearly as good as the above suggestion.

```
    meta_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  -- keep after all
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY(post_id, meta_key, meta_id),  -- to allow dup meta_key for a post
```

[*Source doc*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta)

**Possible ALTER**

*Caveats:*

- I have no way to test this.
- This does not address the 767 error
- This keeps `meta_id` because some WP user pointed out that it is referenced by other tables.
- It assumes you might have multiple rows for a (post_id, meta_key) combo.  (This seems like poor schema design?)
- All this does is speed up typical `SELECTs` involving postmeta.
- This probably applies to woocommerce, too.
- If you use this, please dump your database and be ready to reload it in case of trouble.

The SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta
    DROP PRIMARY KEY,
    DROP INDEX post_id,
    ADD PRIMARY KEY(post_id, meta_key, meta_id),  -- to allow dup meta_key for a post
    ADD INDEX(meta_id);    -- to keep AUTO_INCREMENT happy
```

**Plugin**  [*WP Index Improvements*](https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/) -- to do that alter, plus others.  (As mentioned in the Comments, below.)

Comment: great BUT can you give a step by step instruction of how to change default to use this? remember most people setup wordpress with the default database setup..so how to get to your solution from the default?

Comment: OK, I added the one SQL statement, plus lots of caveats.

Comment: This solution improved my postmeta query time from 32 seconds to 4.9 seconds.

Comment: @osemec - Thanks for reporting on the performance improvement.

Comment: I've implemented this using your ALTER query on my testing environment and it improved the wp_postmeta performance drastically. This question (and solution) seems to have very little attention in my opinion. Why is that? Are there any drawbacks? I'm kind of worried to alter that table on a production environment with 2M+ postmeta rows. By the way: Everywhere I hear how the wp_postmeta table is badly optimized. How come it STILL is in 2020?

Comment: @KristiánFilo - I feel like a health professional suggesting that you wear a mask.  I have been harping on `postmeta` for years, but with no traction.  Thanks for adding your voice by saying "improved drastically".

Comment: Unbelievably helpful response. Thank you for saving the day, on a database with over 6 million records in post meta.

Comment: @Barry - Do you happen to have any before and after metrics?

Comment: @RickJames and I have a new WordPress plugin, GPL and free, to handle this re-keying of postmeta and  similar tables.  https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/

Comment: @RickJames - I am lead developer for a WooCommerce store with 13 million rows in postmeta, 10 000 products, close to 100 000 orders per year. We have now hit the point where the site slows down during traffic spikes because of slow queries and the large amount of data in the tables. How can I contact you? Maybe I could provide some before and after metrics that can be used to lobby the WordPress/WooCommerce core teams on this issue?

Comment: @TASan - mysql at rjweb dot org -- Did you install the plugin that O.Jones mentioned?  How big are the traffic spikes?  How many `postmeta` rows are there for an 'item'?  Do you have the slowlog turned on?  It will help provide metrics on your site; the can help in judging which end of the performance spectrum your data is.  13M rows in postmeta is just one factor.

Comment: @TASan - And, yes, I would love for the core teams to take the performance issue seriously.  (And I pinged O.Jones.)

Comment: @TASan The plugin I mentioned has a "monitoring" feature in its latest version. Run that for a minute or two at a representative peak-load time, then view it and send me or Rick the exported CSV file. We can take a look at your stuff.  Also, consider using the Redis object cache.

Comment: @TASan, how's it going?

Comment: @RickJames We switched to a more hands-on host that specializes in high-volume sites. No problems after that :)

Comment: @TASan - Which site?  It might be worth recommending.  Does it have our plugin, or the equivalent?

Comment: @RickJames The site I am working on I can't disclose because of my contract, but the host is JCloud on jcloud.no - they don't have the best-looking website, but they have technical expertise for sure. It does not have your plugin, but the host is very hands-on with optimizing both indexes and queries. And for the price I don't think it can be beat.

Comment: @TASan - I would be interested to see if their `SHOW CREATE TABLE wp_postmeta` looks any better than ours (after improving the indexes).

Comment: @RickJames [...]
  PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`),
  KEY `post_id` (`post_id`),
  KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`(191)),
  KEY `post_id_2` (`post_id`,`meta_key`(32),`meta_value`(64)),
  KEY `meta_key_2` (`meta_key`(32),`meta_value`(64)),
  FULLTEXT KEY `meta_key_3` (`meta_key`,`meta_value`)

This is kind of constantly adjusted for us when we hit problems. We use the FULLTEXT index for order searches for instance. We have about 330 million rows in postmeta right now :)

Comment: @TASan - Interesting.  (1) I don't think the Optimizer makes any use of columns after the first "prefix", as in (meta_key(32),meta_value(64)); (2) The FULLTEXT is an interesting addition, but requires SQL changed to make use of it.  Will your WP generate MATCH...?

Comment: Nothing in WordPress core exploits FULLTEXT indexes. They require MATCH directives in queries to be useful. It's possible you have a plugin that uses MATCH. If you have an InnoDB Barracuda-based DBMS (recent versions of MySQL and MariaDB) our experience shows you're better off with a different clustered index than `(meta_id)`. Please read this. https://www.plumislandmedia.net/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/tables_and_keys/#compound-primary-keys

Comment: @RickJames It's just a simple matter of hooking in to overwrite the order search to make use of match. We handle a lot of cases that our customer reps use a lot and bypass the search if exact match on an order number, do a simple select on email adress if containing an @ etc. Your experience might be right, I am no database expert at all! But if we see slow queries and problems we just contact the host and they adjust for us. Since everything works now and has for months, it has not been a thing I have thought about. Thanks for the link anyway!

Comment: @O.Jones Of course the thanks for the link was to you  And to Rick regarding the optimizer: Not my expertise, but the host said that for some queries the optimizer chose a bad index or didn't have it or something. Don't quote me on that and it's probably not what they meant. But after they added that "stuff" things got resolved 

Comment: It's a rare ops person at a WordPress-intensive hosting company that knows much about this issue. (Prove me wrong, hosting company DBAs! Join the core performance team!) The indexes in your comment are definitely suboptimal on modern MariaDB / MySql: the 191 hack is not needed.

Comment: @TASan - What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @RickJames 8.0.31-cluster

Comment: The `(191)` is unnecessary in 8.0 _and_ hurts performance.  Point that out to the JCloud IT staff.